# How to embed <script> video in Shadowbox.js

Tags: javascript, shadowbox, ooyala

I'd like to embed a video delivered by Ooyala in a Shadowbox.js object using Wordpress. I've successfully installed Shadowbox.js and tested it with images and videos. The syntax for Shadowbox is something like:

```
<a href="mymovie.swf" rel="shadowbox;height=140;width=120">My Movie</a>
```

However, Ooyala's embed feature uses a . If I pull the href out of the script, I don't get the full player controls. Is there anyway to embed a script tag inside the a tag and have it display in the shadowbox?